# How to take out delimiter before transposing column to row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 4 cells of delimited data: `A1:A3` has the data--delimited by a `;`. A1 has `red;blue;yellow`, A2 has `green;orange`, A3 has `pink;purple`. How can I ungroup this data and then use this code to transpose it like this:

```
Sub convertMultipleRowsToOneRow()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As worsheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim myrange As Range, destR As Range
    Set myrange = ws.Range("A1:A3")
    Set destRng = ws.Range("B1")

    For i = 1 To 3
        myrange.Rows(i).Copy destRng
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 2 + 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

end result to look like this:

[image: Transpose]

Comment: Depending on your Excel version you won't need vba to do this. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @JvdV I know  power query can do this, but the person I'm helping with this request doesn't have an excel version with it, nor can he get access because of the admins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA approach using `Split`.

```
Sub convertMultipleRowsToOneRow()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Dim myrange As Range, destR As Range
Dim v As Variant, i As Long
Set myrange = ws.Range("A1:A3")

For i = 1 To 3
    v = Split(myrange(i), ";")
    ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(v) + 1).Value = v 'change first number of Cells to change row
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If I wanted to place the data below, in row 4 (A4:G4), would I change the last line before `Next` to `Cells(3,1).offset(1).resize(UBound(v)+1).value = v`?

Comment: Nice. If I may make a small comment. Your current use of `Cells` is implicit. I'd make sure of previously declared wb/ws to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, added. Easiest way to change output row would be in `Cells(4,columns.count)...`.

Answer (score 2):

A small edit to your code worked for me:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim myrange As Range, destR As Range
    Set myrange = ws.Range("A1:A3")
    Set destRng = ws.Range("B1")
    
    arr = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(myrange.Value), ";"), ";")
    destRng.Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: if i wanted to place the data from A1:A3 into A4:G4, what would that look like? Same concept, but not appending it into row 1 column B, but it's own separate row below the initial data being split

Comment: change your `destRng` to `A4`? @NidenK

Comment: I appreciate the help, is there any way to accept both answers?

Comment: No, there is not. And that also doesn't matter. You must pick what worked best for you and I'm not fussed if that's not mine. However, you could appreciate any answer by upvoting them.

Comment: Hey i have one more question. Say I just have one cell, how would I change `arr = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(myrange.Value), ";"), ";")` to refence cell A5 if i change the `myrange` reference up top?

Comment: As in, say my range is no longer multiple rows, but just one cell with a ton of data points delimited and need to be transposed and split.